# can a DSP combine two 48khz audio streams to create a 96khz output

Tags: audio, signal-processing, audio-processing

Wireless connections like bluetooth are limited by transmission bandwidth resulting in a limited bitrate and audio sampling frequency.

Can a high definition audio output like 24bit/96khz be created by combining two separate audio streams of 24bit/48khz each, transmitted from a source to receiver speakers/earphones.

I tried to understand how a DSP(digital signal processor) works, but I am unable to find the exact technical words that explain this kind of audio splitting and re-combining technique for increasing the audio resolution

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to upsample the two original audio streams to 96 kHz. Combining two audio streams will not increase audio resolution; all you're really doing is summing two streams together.

You'll probably want to read this [free DSP resource](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple construction which could be used to create two audio streams at 24bit/48kHz from a higher resolution 24bit/96kHz stream, which could later be recombined to recreate a single audio stream at 24bit/96kHz.

Starting with an initial high resolution source at 24bit/96kHz `{x[0],x[1],x[2],...}`:

1. Take every even sample of the source (i.e. `{x[0],x[2],x[4],...}` ), and send it over your first 24bit/48kHz channel (i.e. producing the stream `y1` such that `y1[0]=x[0], y1[1]=x[2], ...`).
2. At the same time, take every odd sample `{x[1],x[3],x[5],...}` of the source, and send it over your second 24bit/48kHz channel (i.e. producing the stream `y2` such that `y2[0]=x[1], y2[1]=x[3], ...`).

At the receiving end, you should then be able to reconstruct the original 24bit/96kHz audio signal by interleaving the samples from your first and second channel. In other words you would be recreating an output stream `out` with:

```
out[0] = y1[0]; // ==x[0]
out[1] = y2[0]; // ==x[1]
out[2] = y1[1]; // ==x[2]
out[3] = y2[1]; // ==x[3]
out[4] = y1[2]; // ==x[4]
out[5] = y2[2]; // ==x[5]
...
```

That said, transmitting those two streams of 24bit/48kHz would require an effective bandwidth of `2*24bit*48000kHz = 2304kbps`, which is exactly the same as transmitting one stream of 24bit/96kHz. So, while this allows you to fit the audio stream in channels of fixed bandwidth, you are not reducing the total bandwidth requirement this way.

Answer (score 0):

Could please you provide you definition of "combining".   Based on the data rates, it seems like you want to do a multiplex (combining two mono channels into a stereo channel).  If the desire is to "add" two channels together (two monos into a single mono or two stereo channels into one stereo), then you should not have to increase your sampling rate (you are adding two band limited signals, increasing the sampling rate is not necessary).